# Webpack Clean- /public/js has been removed

Tags: javascript, plugins, npm, webpack

I am using the clean-webpack-plugin to clean out my public/js folder.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-webpack-plugin

I have tried everything but always get a **/public/js has been removed**

```
plugins: [
new CleanWebpackPlugin(['js/'], {
            root: '/public',
            verbose: true,
            dry: false,
            exclude: ['360.jpg']
    }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing your `root: '/public',` key value and remove forward slash from `['js/']`

if you really need a `root` key in your settings, make sure it is an absolute path:

`root: __dirname` or `root: "E:/node_projects/my_project",`

Plugin does work for me with these settings:

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], {
    //root: '/',
    verbose: true,
    dry: false,
    exclude: ['example.txt']
}),
```

My project setup:

[image]

Here is my console output:

[image]